# How to open movie in nsis script?

Tags: nsis, movie

I want during installation, the movie is set to be broadcast at the same time, how can this be done?

For example:
Open movie file with windows mediaplayer (fullscreen) from `D:\movie\test.avi`.

Please give me an example!

Comment: A installer that plays a fullscreen video automatically, that is insane. I would uninstall your software immediately and add your entire company to my hate list. There are also technical issues; you don't know which players are installed and if they support whatever codec you used. Remember that there are "Windows N" versions that don't have WMP installed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky question. I suppose easiest way is to **ExecShell** the .avi file directly with "open" parameter:

```
ExecShell "open" "D:\movie\test.avi"
```

Of course the file must exist - so you need to copy it first e.g. to $INSTDIR folder (avoid using absolute paths).

But this approach depends on Windows configuration (which app is associated with .avi format).

The second option is to detect whether **mediaplayer** software is installed and run it with .avi file as parameter.

Detecting the mediaplayer can be done through registry - but each software has it's own way so there is no exact solution.

Comment: Don't specify the "open" verb. The verb should _always_ be a empty string unless you want to execute a specific action. If I look at the WMP11.AssocFile.AVI prog id on my machine I see that it has both a open and a play verb and the play verb is the default. I assume that if you force the open verb then it might just load the file without starting playback. The best solution would be to check if the play verb exists and if not, fall back to a empty string...